# Using Cohen's kappa with tensorflow and keras

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, metrics

I am desperately trying to use cohen kappa's metric as either a loss function or an evaluation metric in my keras neural network. I have tried many different implementations of it online and none of them seem to be maintained. In particular due to the fact that tf.contrib no longer exists in tensorflow 2.0. Any help in pointing in me in the right direction of a working implementation will be much appreciated!

When using the tf add-on class found here https://www.tensorflow.org/addons/api_docs/python/tfa/metrics/cohens_kappa.

I keep getting the following error and have no idea how I would go about debugging this.

`ValueError: Number of samples in y_true and y_pred are different`

Comment: Can you post your code and full error trace?